# Upgrade Joomla 3.4 RC to 3.4 final

Tags: update, cms-testing, joomla-3.4

I have a Joomla testing site where I installed Joomla 3.4 Release Candidate. I'm aware that there's no Upgrade path from beta Versions to final Versions

> ...please do not upgrade any of your production sites to the release
>   candidate as it is ONLY intended for testing and there is no upgrade
>   path from pre-release packages.

(http://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5585-joomla-3-4-rc-released.html)

But is it possible in some way to do this upgrade manually, or force the upgrade to the final Joomla 3.4 release? It would save me some time to be able to continue using the testing environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just did a quick test, and it looks like you can unzip the [Joomla 3.4 Full package](http://www.joomla.org/download.html) to your testing environment, overwriting any existing files. After removing the `installation` folder (not required for testing releases, but final releases requires you to remove this folder), everything seems to be working, and Joomla admin area reports `Joomla! 3.4.0`.

I don't know if this gives a complete upgrade, but for a testing environment it should work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Generally whilst we state that there is no upgrade path generally you can upgrade between releases fine. Especially on test sites. The differences occur for example during alpha1 and beta1 we introduced a new plugin for the new google recaptcha. At beta 2 we then removed it again and merged it with the existing plugin. That meant if you upgraded you would still have the plugin installed but it would not be maintained etc. The same goes for new files added and removed during the release period (and obviously we don't guarantee the security of said files - although we try and ensure they are as good as possible).

Since 3.2.2 we can have multiple database files per release so you database schema should always stay upto date (which used to be the major issue with upgrade paths).

In summary you should never upgrade live sites or base them on non-stable releases for the reason I listed in the first paragraph but for a straightforward testing site you should be fine just upgrading as usual via the Joomla upgrade component :)

On a personal note if it's just from 3.4 RC to live then I can tell you (as I released both) that there are none of the above issues from RC to the stable release. A very low number of changes were made between the RC and the stable release.